# how can I highlight text with the following effect

Tags: highlighting, text-decorations, text-manipulation

how can I highlight text with the following effect? The darkness of the color indicates the importance of the text.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one approach using TikZ.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
100
\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{\node[opacity=0](A) {centavos};
\shade[inner color=blue] (A.south east) rectangle (A.north west);
\path (A.center) \pgfextra{\pgftext{centavos}};}, represented by
\end{document}
```

[image: highlight]